# Exporting 3D scenes in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I encountered the problem while exporting scene into 3D in ArcScene.

All other shapefiles work fine and are exported to 3d format, but the files involving "circle" as the construction tool makes ArcScene stop responding, and the file that has been created gives vrml parsing error.

What could be the possible solution?

I have used different versions of ArcGIS Desktop, like 10.1, 10.4. and different windows with updated 3d builder.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation and web to see if that tool supports true curves?

Comment: I could not find any reason. And yes tool support true curves

Comment: Can you provide a link to where it says that tool supports true curves, please?